# Getting started with Darwin Streaming Server

Tags: streaming, apple

Has somebody a good guide for getting started using Darwin Streaming Server and Darwin Proxy Server? I've searched in the Internet with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using it for about a year and a half now, and it appears to be a black box.  No instrumentation, no decent low-level docs, not much community around it.  The only advice I have is that, depending on the OS, you will probably need to try out both version 5.5.5 and the version 6 builds, and then resort to source compile.  In my experience, both of those versions binary builds segfault on FC/CentOS with absurd regularity.  The binary builds also defecate on your filesystem in a lot of stupid ways.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning we considered using DSS because it was free and it was Apple. However we switched to Wowza Media Server later on, since DSS had limited support and a lack of community around it.

If you are determined to go with DSS check out [its admin's guide](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/server/streaming/qtss_admin_guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we looked at it, tried to use it, failed utterly (which is saying something for the BSD nerd I have working with me), and ended up going with Real Media's Helix server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial i used:
http://blog.rachaelbond.com/darwin-media-server/

When that is done and you are on the localhost:1220 page, go to playlists and add an mp4 file to test with. Then click play next to the new playlist's name.

For my case i had the server on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 12.04 32bits) and tested out the rtsp stream on windows using vlc.

just enter: rtsp://:554/

Worked for me!